# Using two arrays in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've got 2 arrays. both are text fields. I want to make textfield2 clear up when a keyup is triggered on textField1. how can I use both arrays in a keyup function?

```
var showItem=['orange', 'beans', 'rose'];
var typeItem=['fruit', 'veggie', 'flower'];
```

I tried using a for loop but does not work as expected.

```
for (i = 0; i < showItem.length; i++) {
    $('#' + showItem[i]).keyup(function () {
        console.log(typeItem[i]);
        $('#' + typeItem[i]).text('');
    });
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run that code? You need to define better what "does not work as expected" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that all of the callbacks refer to a single variable `i` which is changing over time as you iterate through the array.

Instead of using a for-loop to iterate, you can elegantly use [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) as an excuse to create separate closures for each of the callbacks. Then each inner function will have a reference to its own `i` value which will be effectively constant.

```
showItem.forEach(function(item, i) {
    $('#'+item).keyup(function(){
        $('#'+typeItem[i]).text('');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:**

Value of `i` at the time when event is fired is 4 and there is no item at fourth index in both arrays, so `$('#'+typeItem[i]).text('');` will not work.

**Solution:**

The code can be wrapped in IIFE and `i` can be passed to it, so that it'll be cached for each element. However, there's a better solution.

Use `Array#indexOf` to get the index of the clicked element.

```
var showItem = ['orange', 'beans', 'rose'];
var typeItem = ['fruit', 'veggie', 'flower'];

var selector = '#' + showItem.join(', #'); // '#orange, #beans, #rose'

$(selector).keyup(function () {
    // Get index of the id of the clicked element from array
    var index = showItem.indexOf($(this).attr('id'));

    // Get the element at index from second array and set the innerText to empty string
    $('#' + typeItem[index]).text('');
});
```